# How to assign particular return variable in function on if/else statement in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, return

I have two functions as below:

```
def abc():
    i = "False"
    j = "100"
    return i,j

def xyz():
    if abc() == "False":  #I want to compare "False" with variable "i"
       print("Not Done")
    else:
        abc() == "101"    ##I want to compare "False" with variable "j"
        print("something else:")
xyz()
```

Current Output:

```
something else:
```

Expected Output:

```
Not Done
```

I want to know how to check particular `return` variable for particular if/else statement.

Comment: abc() returns a tuple. a tuple can never be equal to a string.

Comment: You're missing `if` before the second condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply this?

```
def xyz():
    i, j = abc()
    if i == "False":
        print("Not Done")
    elif j == "101":
        print("something else:")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your code to work, since your function is returning a tuple:

```
def abc():
    i = "False"
    j = "100"
    return i,j

def xyz():
    if abc()[0] == "False":  #I want to compare "False" with variable "i" #[0] for i
       print("Not Done")
    else:
        abc()[1] == "101"    ##I want to compare "False" with variable "j" #[1] for j
        print("something else:")
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm guessing that you want to print not done if any variable inside your function abc() is "False". In that case here's the answer:

```
def abc():
i = "False"
j = "100"
return i,j
m,n=abc()
def xyz():
    if m or n == "False":  #I want to compare "False" with variable "i"
       print("Not Done")
    else:
                                    ##I want to compare "False" with variable "j"
        print("something else:")
xyz()
```